# Getting the combination of facevalues that gives the highest score in a dicegame

Tags: algorithm

Working on a dicegame for school and I have trouble figuring out how to do automatic calculation of the result. (we don't have to do it automatically, so I could just let the player choose which dice to use and then just check that the user choices are valid) but now that I have started to think about it I can't stop...

the problem is as follows:
I have six dice, the dice are normal dice with the value of 1-6.
In this example I have already roled the dice and they have the following values:

```
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

But I don't know how to calulate all combinations so that as many dicecombinations as possible whose value combined(addition) are 3 (in this example) are used.

The values should be added together (for example a die with value 1 and another die with the value 2 are together 3) then there are different rounds in the game where the aim is to get different values (which can be a combination(addition) of die-values for example 
dicevalues: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
could give the user a total of 12 points if 4 is the goal for the current round)

```
2 + 2 = 4
2 + 2 = 4
2 + 2 = 4
```

if the goal of the round instead where 6 then the it would be

```
2 + 2 + 2 = 6  
2 + 2 + 2 = 6
```

instead which would give the player 12 points (6 + 6)

```
[1, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

with the goal of 3 would only use the dice with value 3 and discard the rest since there is no way to add them up to get three.

```
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 1 = 3
```

would give the user 9 points.
but if it where calculated the wrong way and the ones where used up together instead of each 1 getting apierd with a two 1 + 1 + 1 which would only give the player 3 points och the twos couldn't be used.

Another example is:
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
and all combinations that are equal to 6 gives the user points

```
[6], [5, 1], [4 ,2]
```

user gets 18 points (3 * 6)
    [1 ,2 ,3], [6] 
user gets 12 points (2 * 6) (Here the user gets six points less due to adding upp 1 + 2 + 3 instead of doing like in the example above)

A dice can have a value between 1 and 6.

I haven't really done much more than think about it and I'm pretty sure that I could do it right now, but it would be a solution that would scale really bad if I for example wanted to use 8 dices instead and every time I start programming on it I start to think that have to be a better/easier way of doing it... Anyone have any suggestion on where to start? I tried searching for an answer and I'm sure it's out there but I have problem forumulating a query that gives me relevant result...

Comment: Edit the question.Set the task. What is the set of possible combinations of  facevalues. How is the score counted for a combination of facevalues. After that we can look for the algoritm for looking for the best combination. And reread your text. What is " I'm pretty that I could do"? We should solve your task, not your text.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by set the task?
also not sure what you mean by "what is the set of possible combinations of facevalues"... If the goal is to get 4 four ones and two twos can be combined to to give 4 two times for example like 1+1+1+1 and 2+2 since the player get 4 two times the score for 4 will be 4+4. If the user instead choose to use there dice for fives the would only get 5 points (2+1+1+1 or 2+2+1) the oher dice would be disregarded.

Comment: The restriction on how it should be counted is that it should always count in favor of the player which means that all combinations needs to be taken in consideration.

Comment: If you want to find the maximal f(A), you should define the set to which that A belongs and that function f. Without that, it is all empty talks. I am merely showing what you have to define if you want "the combination of facevalues that gives the highest score". If you don't know, what does it mean, why did you use it?

Comment: "I have six dice: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]" 3 dice of 2 sides and three of one side? Or 6 dice having 3 sides with 2 points and three with 1 point? Or they are normal (or other ) dice, that are numbered in that strange way? People here can help with editing, but they must understand smth that you need. We can't edit what has no sense.

Comment: What is a combination of dice? What is "values combined"? What do you do with them to combine? Sum? Concatenation? Multiplication? Very rarely I close questions, but now I have a strong wish to do it, if you won't work on it!

Answer (score 0):

With problems that look confusing like this, it is a really good idea to start with some working and examples. We have 6 die, with range [1 to 6]. The possible combinations we could make therefore are:

```
target = 2

1 combination: 2
2 combination: 1+1

target = 3

1 combination: 3
2 combination: 2+1
3 combination: 1+1+1

target = 4

1 combination: 4
2 combination: 3+1 
               2+2
3 combination: 2+1+1
4 combination: 1+1+1+1

target = 5

1 combination: 5
2 combination: 4+1
               3+2
3 combination: 2+2+1
4 combination: 2+1+1+1
5 combination: 1+1+1+1+1
```

See the pattern? Hint, we go backwards from target to 1 for the first number we can add, and then given this first number, and the size of the combination, there is a limit to how big subsequent numbers can be!

There is a finite list of possible combinations. You can by looking for 1 combination scores, and remove these from the die available. Then move on to look for 2 combination scores, etc.

If you want to read more about this sub-field of mathematics, the term you need to look for is "Combinatorics". Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, on vacation right now drinking a beer in the sun but I will absolutely follow up on your tip on a less sunny day. :)